# Removing a specific element from an array

Tags: arrays, object, indexof, array-splice

I have an array called hotelList where the user is asked by prompt to enter

`name`;
`numberOfRooms`;
`numberOfFloors`;
`surfaceOfHotel`;

now, for example when I want to remove an hotel which right in the middle of the array, I am tryiong this code:

```
function eliminateHotel() {
  const userPrompt = prompt(
    "introduce el nombre del hotel que quieras eliminar"
  );
  console.log(hotelList.indexOf(userPrompt === hotelList.name));
  console.log (hotelList.splice(hotelList.indexOf(userPrompt === hotelList.name)))
  console.log(hotelList)
```

but when I try to do it, it will only eliminate the last element of the array. Not the one I chose.

Can you please help?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

try to use `findIndex`:

```
const index = hotelList.findIndex(el => userPrompt  == el.name);
if(index > -1) hotelList.splice(index,1);
```

Comment: thanks but it did not work. it only eliminated the first one

Comment: Another way, you can iterate over the list of elements using forEach with index and try to append each index equal to userPrompt in array of number after that you will have an array of all indexes equal to userPrompt then you can choose the middle index you want to splice